# c# Build a project from another project

Tags: c#, build, executable

The Title Might be totaly wrong about my question , i apologize for that 
I have 2 Projects (c# Form Applications) in the same Solution , I want To be able to Build the seconde project from the another one .

For example `Form1` in The `Project 1` have a button that once it clicked it build an `executable` of  `Project 2` .

**EDIT :** 
 My Application will be separated as 2 `executables` (Server and Client ) I want The Server to be able to build his own Client `executable`
so  I want to be able to save The Client executable to the path i want programmatically using `FileDialog'

For example Adding the exectuable of the Client in the Server resources and save it on a selected path `(Dialog)` by the user that uses the Server

Comment: What exactly is the goal - what types or project is "Project 2"

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this?

Comment: Lets say My Application will be separated as 2 `executables` (Server and Client ) I want The Server to be able to build his own Client `executable`

Comment: This seems like a **really** strange thing to do... You could look into calling MSBuild on button click. But I still fail to see why you would need to do this. If you just need to build both at once, simply add them to the same solution.

Comment: @DangerZone I just want to be able to save The Client executable to the path i want programmatically using `FileDialog'

Comment: That is not what "once it clicked it build an executable of Project 2" means. You should update your question if you don't want to actually *build* a new client.

Comment: Just add reference from proj1 to project2 and will see, that compiled project2.exe exists in project1/bin/debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved By Using Mono.cecil reference 
Documentation about the reference :

[can be found here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/)